# Is there a symbol for comparing coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, notation, partial-fractions

While doing PFs, ODEs or many other things, comparing coefficients often come up. Is it wrong to use the '**=**' for comparing coefficients, e.g. '*$4x^2$ + 3x **=** Ax ∴ A=3*'. Or is there a correct symbol to use?

Comment: Coming from where I do, I would say $4x^2+3x\equiv Ax\pmod{x^2}$, but  I’m not sure that your audience would see the appropriateness of this.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> This way it follows from the equality
> \begin{align*}
> 4x^2+3=Ax
> \end{align*}
> the equality
> \begin{align*}
> 3=[x]\left(4x^2+3\right)=[x](Ax)=A
> \end{align*}
> of the coefficients of $x$.

**Note:** See for instance formula (5.53) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R. L. Graham, D. Knuth and O. Patashnik for more information.